# Third level in the folder hierarchy using Relative Path

Tags: path

I'm trying to use relative path to link back to the index.htm in a webpage I'm making.

Can relative path go beyond "../" , can it go beyond 2 dots ??

It's not working when I use ".../" , 3 dots.

Answer (score 5):

Jon answered this in his comment, you need to repeat ../ for each level you want to go up